# Switching the status of a state machine from inside a loop

Tags: c, arrays, state-machine, kernighan-and-ritchie

I have an array (`nchar[12]`) and I wrote this code to print it as vertical columns composed of "X"'s.

I first wrote a version with an accumulator and a while-loop and it worked fine, but it only could print colums as long as a given limit.

Then I tried to write it as a state machine, but the output is just an endless series of blank spaces.

I declared status as an int and assigned a value of 1 to it, then:

```
while (status = 1) {
    for (i = 1; i <= 12; ++i) {
        status = 0;
        if (nchar[i] > 0) {
            printf("  X");
            --nchar[i];
            status = 1;
        }
        else
            printf("   ");
    }
```

It should stop when it doesn't find any value to print for the last processed line, but it just goes on forever and I don't understand why.

Comment: if you declare nchar[12] then you must loop from 0 to 11, not from 1 to 12.

Comment: I'm a little worried about the loop and the index variable `i` starting at `1` and going up to *and including* `12`. I'm worried about that because arrays are indexed, as you should know, from zero to size minus one. So if `nchar` is an array of size 12 the indexes goes from `0` to `11`.

Comment: As for how to solve your problem, learn to use a debugger, because then you can use it to step through your code line by line to see what happens.

Comment: I'm sorry, the array goes up to 13, then Ihave it read from 1 to 12 that's the span I need my output from (the array is written by storing the number of words of a certain length, thus excluding words woth zero letters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loop never ends because `=` is the assignment operator not `==` which is the comparision operator. You probably want

```
while (status == 1)
```

Or simply

```
while (status)
```

instead of

```
while (status = 1)
```

Also if you have an array declared as

```
type nchar[12];
```

then the valid indices for it start from 0 and end at 11. So, your loop should start with `i=0` and should loop until `i<12` becomes false.

Comment: To never again fail because of such an annoying mistake, you might like to go for Yoda-Conditions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions @maja

Comment: thank you, it really was as simple as that.   ||  as for the array, I wrote 12 but the array is really set to 13, then I use the last 12 entries because of the nature of the prgram.